# using rake db:migrate with sinatra and activerecord (not rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sqlite, sinatra

I am using rake with sinatra and activerecord (not rails).  I have two model classes - Admin (in admin.rb) and Bill (bill.rb).  I was able to run rake db:create_migrations with the following output (but I cannot see any tables in the database - sqlite).  Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

```
== 20150907135939 CreateAdmins: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:admins)
   -> 0.0011s
== 20150907135939 CreateAdmins: migrated (0.0012s) =============================

== 20150907140840 CreateBills: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:bills)
   -> 0.0005s
== 20150907140840 CreateBills: migrated (0.0006s) =============================
```

**Rakefile**

```
# Rakefile

require './app'
require 'sinatra'
require 'active_record'
require 'sinatra/activerecord/rake'
```

**Gemfile**

```
# Gemfile

source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem "sinatra"
gem "activerecord"
gem "sinatra-activerecord"
gem 'sinatra-flash'
gem 'sinatra-redirect-with-flash'
gem 'rake'
gem 'sqlite3'

=begin
group :development do
 gem 'sqlite3'
 gem "tux"
end

group :production do
 gem 'sqlite3'
end
=end
```

When I run the following query in a test.rb file I get an exception:

```
puts("type email address of admin")
admin_email = gets.chomp
find_admin = Admin.find_by(email:admin_email) # read
puts("admin retrieved with email: #{find_admin.email} and name: #{find_admin.name}")
```

Exception:

```
test.rb:41:in `<main>': undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Object I get back is nil (I checked using find_admin.nil?)

Comment: Try to populate the tables with some data and check wither activerecord reports an error.

Comment: I did not get an error with Ruby (I used Admin.create! and passed the parameters).  However, I do not get anything back when I type select * from admins when I'm in the sqlite shell).

Comment: check and make sure that everything is running in the same environment? That you aren't populating the Dev DB, and reading from the Prod. Also look at the the db files on disk and make sure that everything is looking in the same place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, try to [strip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-strip) the leading and trailing whitespaces after you take the input email, like this:

```
admin_email = gets.chomp.strip
puts "admin_email: #{admin_email.inspect}"
```

Then, try your script again. It should work.

To explain what's going on here, your query:

```
find_admin = Admin.find_by(email:admin_email)
```

this can't find an admin record with the provided email. So, it's a `nil` object and when you call: `find_admin.email` i.e. `nil.email` then you get the error:

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

You need to make sure you have an admin with the given email. To do that, you can create one first, in your rails console, do this:

```
Admin.create!(email: 'testadmin@test.com')
```

Then, try to find the admin like above by giving `testadmin@test.com` as input.

It should work if the admin record with the given email is present in the database.

Comment: I solved it earlier - forgot to update here.  The user was not being saved correctly.

Comment: I thought I did accept but apparently not - I accepted it now.  Thank you for your help.